# Bokeh output_file does not show in html

Tags: python, bokeh

I am building a webpage with some bokeh plots in it and have been using Jupyter Notebooks to build the plots. However, now I need the plots to show in html and not in the notebooks, but for some reason the plots do not show. Below I have included a very simple plot taken from bokeh's page:

```
# prepare some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

# output to static HTML file
output_file("lines.html")

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend_label="Temp.", line_width=2)

# show the results
show(p)
```

When I run the code a new tab opens but it is empty. If I run `save` instead of `show` the same problems occurs as the file is empty when I open it.

Answer (score 1):

`save` and `show` (after `output_file`) both work for me. In the following example, both files `lines-a.html` and `lines-b.html` are created:

```py
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import save, output_file, show

output_file("lines-a.html")

# prepare some data
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [6, 7, 2, 4, 5]

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title="simple line example", x_axis_label='x', y_axis_label='y')

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
p.line(x, y, legend_label="Temp.", line_width=2)

# show the results
save(p, "lines-b.html", title="Test")
show(p)
```

Comment: When I run the code the tab opens up empty and the saved html file is also empty. I don't know how it is possible?

Comment: @andKaae None of my files are empty, both contain the expected figure. Did you run exactly my snippet, and nothing else, in a fresh notebook session? If so, I'd suspect a problem with your config or something.

Comment: Yeah I tried running it in a fresh notebook at same result. I was affraid it might be that, do you have any idea how to solve it?